# expected enum `Result<_, pallet::Error<T>>`

Tags: polkadot, rust

I write codes for add item in storage but when I run this command `cargo build --release` it show me this error :

```rs
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
     --> /home/kianoush/projects/dortaj_pay/pallets/bussines/src/lib.rs:248:6
      |
  230 | /             match _itemInfo{
  231 | |                 _ => Err(<Error<T>>::StoreItemNotFound),
      | |                      ---------------------------------- this is found to be of type `Result<_, pallet::Error<T>>`
  232 | |                 Some(item) => {
  233 | |                     let user_basket_item = UserBasketItemItem {
  ...   |
  248 | |                     <Baskets<T>>::insert(storeId, store_basket);
      | |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Result`, found `()`
  249 | |                 }
  250 | |             }
      | |_____________- `match` arms have incompatible types
      |
      = note:   expected enum `Result<_, pallet::Error<T>>`
              found unit type `()`
  note: return type inferred to be `Result<_, pallet::Error<T>>` here
```

this is my code :

```rs
match _itemInfo{
    None => Err(<Error<T>>::StoreItemNotFound),
    Some(item) => {
        let user_basket_item = UserBasketItemItem {
            itemId: item_id,
            price: item.price,
            count: count_item,
        };

        let mut add_item: Vec<UserBasketItemItem> = Vec::new();
        add_item.push(user_basket_item);

        let store_basket = Basket {
            itemId: Self::gen_dna(),
            confirmPay: false,
            customerPay: false,
            items: add_item,
        };
        <Baskets<T>>::insert(storeId, store_basket);
    }
}
```

**what is the problem ? how can i solve that ?**

Comment: First of all that is a normal rust error, the match arms must return same types, first resolve that and convert the error type to                                                                             
 Pallet::Error type None => Err(<Error<T>>::StoreItemNotFound.into()),   And make sure the there is enum variant StorageItemNotFound in your error enum.

Comment: @MrishoLukamba still show me error

Comment: Please read the error message. Its very clear what you have to do. Your match arms has different return types

Comment: @MrishoLukamba I Read that but i dont know how  can i solve that

Comment: Code related questions can only be properly answered when the full code is present. Please add a link to GitHub or some other public code hoster with the complete example, not just a snippet, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
`match` arms have incompatible types
```

That's the reason. This is a pure Rust problem. So, I edited the tags.

```rs
let foo = match bar {
  "baz" => Err(()),
  // The previous return type is a `Result`, so you also need to return a `Result` here
  "qux" => Ok(()),
}
```

```rs
let foo = match bar {
  // If you want to ignore the `Result`, make it returning empty here
  "baz" => { Err(()); }
  "qux" => (),
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but my problem for this error : ` ^^^^^^ expected `()`, found enum `Result`
`

Comment: still show me this error

Comment: That is the error. And the reason is what I said. Did you try to update the code as I wrote?

Comment: Yes I did , but i did

Answer (score 1):

This *is* a pure rust problem both arms of the match must return the same type. I assume you intend to return the result of this match

but since

```
        <Baskets<T>>::insert(storeId, store_basket);
```

ends with a `;` this arm will return `()` instead of a `Result< ... >` remove this and the return type will be that from the last statement in the block, hopefully the type you are expecting.